# What is the notation for a sequence of elements (non number elements)?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I am new to math and am exploring how to formally represent a sequence of events. I want to be able to say "an event sequence $E_s$ is a sequence of events $\langle e_1, e_2,\ldots, e_n\rangle$". Just basically trying to define a sequence of objects.

What is the appropriate way to do that (in set theory notation, or something better if that is what is typical)?

I have done some searches, but all the examples/definitions of "sequences in set theory" I've seen have to do with numbers, so not sure if it's different when not dealing with numbers.

Comment: What you did is perfectly standard, even the notation (albeit with proper $\TeX$, i.e. $\langle\ldots \rangle$). A finite sequence if any function whose domain is $[n]$, for some natural number $n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, in set theory, everything is generally considered to be a set. So sequences are sets, and the sequenced objects are also sets. We can give those sets meanings and call them by $1,2,3$ and so on, or $\pi,e,\sqrt{-1}$ and so forth.

In general, a sequence is a function. Finite sequences are functions whose domain is finite, so usually it's taken as some $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ for some natural number $n$. This means that we can write it as some $f(1)$ to $f(n)$. But it is common to write $\langle e_1,\ldots,e_n\rangle$ or $\langle e_i\mid 1\leq i\leq n\rangle$ as well.

As for the definition, it seems to me that you've nailed it. Writing *"An event sequence $E_s$ is a sequence of events $\langle e_1,\ldots,e_n\rangle$"* is very clear and to the point.